# java slick2d - key press being ignored

Tags: java, slick

I have the following in my update funtion. The first input for key_enter when textPos!=2 works fine, but the one when textPos==2 doesn't work. The key up and down work fine though.

The System.out.println("Enter: " + choice); never gets printed

```
public void update() {
        Input input = gc.getInput();
        if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ENTER)) {
            if (textShowing && textPos != 2) {
                textPos++;
                textShowing = false;
            }
        }
        if (textShowing && textPos == 2) {
            if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ENTER)) {
                System.out.println("Enter: " + choice);
                if (choice == 0) {

                } else if (choice == 1) {

                } else {
                    textPos++;
                    textShowing = false;
                    System.out.println("Text Pos: " + textPos);
                }
            } else if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_UP)) {
                if (choice > 0) {
                    choice--;
                }
            } else if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
                if (choice < 2) {
                    choice++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching the debugger? Set a break point, check your variable values. Pay special attention to `textShowing` and the value of `textPos`.

Comment: Figured it out. If i switch the "if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ENTER))" and "if (textShowing && textPos != 2) {" the other way around it works

Comment: You might want to enter that as an answer to this post, and mark it answered :)

Comment: Wouldn't let me answer it yesterday as I didn't have enough rep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If i switch the "if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.KEY_ENTER))" and "if (textShowing && textPos != 2) {" the other way around it works